# Email Replies in Salesforce

Tags: email, activityhistory, custom-activity

We use Sales cloud and are making the switch to lightning as we speak. We want to get things right from the get go and want to use the activity portion of lightning to its full advantage. We are changing our users work flow to include sending emails from SFDC so we can monitor what they are saying and when in the sales cycle they are communicating with the client.

We already can track how many times an email has been open. Is it possible to track the responses in SFDC? For example a rep sends out an email; it is added to the activity log that is always growing. The client responds and their response is captured in SFDC above the one our rep sent.

I don't need the functionality of our reps viewing the sent email in SFDC. We want this more for reporting purposes. We are already using G-Suite and connected SFDC to G-suite. In Gmail we use the lightning for gmail chrome app.

Let me know if there are any further questions.
Thanks,
Braden